# Is there a GraphLab SFrame.show() equivalent in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, graphlab, sframe

Graphlabs SFrame.show() display a comprehensive view of each column in the SFrame and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in Pandas?

df.describe() just doesn't provide the level of details at a glance that sf.show() does.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is df.describe() as you've already pointed out.  However you might be able to supplement the missing details with further call to pandas functions such as:

`df['A'].value_counts()` - Count the frequency of values in a column

`df['A'].mean()` - Compute the mean of a column

`df['A'].var()` - Compute the variance of a column

`df['A'].std()` - Compute the standard deviation of a column

`df['A'].min()`

`df['A'].max()`

`df['A'].sum()`

etc...

See this [link](https://turi.com/learn/translator/#Computing_statistics_with_data_tables) for more...